# Можно ли задать размеры картинки в селекторе?

Tags: android

Ставлю картинки в табы программно

```
tabSpec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_history));
```

Проблема в том что они заполняют все пространство, можно ли задать размеры в селекторе?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/history_a"
    android:state_selected="true" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/history"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [вот так обернуть селектор](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34225206/3212712) и проставить `padding`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="1dp">

        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- тут селектор -->
        </selector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: еще есть элемент [<inset>](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Inset) для отступов